# Invalid bucket name "": Bucket name must match the regex error, on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I used `chmod +x ./resources/setup.sh && ./resources/setup.sh` on command, and I got an error that is:

> Invalid bucket name "": Bucket name must match the regex error, on AWS. I pasted below setup.sh image.

[image]

Comment: Line 7 seems to be looking for a bucket that include `s3bucket` in its name. It is likely that it can't find such a bucket. Check your tutorial to see whether an earlier step requested you create such a bucket.

Comment: Finally it works! Much obliged :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check your script, apparently the basket name is not returned from line 7, either syntax error, no buckets returned , permission issue..

Comment: Actually, I didn't write this code. It was written by someone who is a teacher in AWS Course on coursera. I just pasted, but it doesn't work. Btw, in line 7, query "Buckets[].Name" , should I write my bucket name instead of "Buckets[].Name", or is it True?